# My bubble sorting algorithm in Java never stops sorting and doesnt return anything

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to make a bubble sorting algorithm in Java however my code just keeps going when It's supposed to sort without returning anything. When the program is run it gets as far as printing the array before the sorting however after that nothing happens but the program doesnt stop it keeps running

```
package src;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class bubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = getLength();

        List<Integer> randomList = createList(length);

        System.out.println("The list before sorting:\n" + randomList);

        List<Integer> newList = sortList(randomList, length);

        System.out.println("The list after sorting:\n" + newList);



    }

    public static int getLength() {
        System.out.println("Please enter how long you want the array to be");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        return length;
    }

    public static List<Integer> createList(int length) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int x = 0 ; x < length ; x++){
            int randomnumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            randomList.add(randomnumber);
        }

        return randomList;  
    }

    public static List<Integer> sortList(List<Integer> randomList, int length){
        boolean sorted = false;

        while(sorted == false){
            sorted = true;

            for(int x = 0 ; x < (length - 1) ; x++) {
                if(randomList.get(x) > randomList.get(x + 1)) {
                    sorted = false;
                    int temp = randomList.get(x + 1);
                    randomList.set((x + 1), (x));
                    randomList.set((x + 1), temp);
                }
            }
        }

        return randomList;
    }

}
```

Comment: `randomList.set((x + 1), (x));` shouldn't that rather be `randomList.set((x + 1), randomList.get(x));`

Comment: what is this for: while(sorted == false){
            sorted = true; ?

Comment: check your swapping code, its incorrect. int temp = randomList.get(x + 1);
                    randomList.set((x + 1), (x));
                    randomList.set((x + 1), temp);

Comment: One of the `randomList.set(x + 1,... );` should presumably be `randomList.set(x, ...);`. Consider creating a `swap` method. Will make your code more readable for yourself.

Comment: Also, do not set a value to `x`. It's your indexing variable, not anything coming from the list of values.

Comment: Take a look at [this great blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to learn how to solve problems like this for yourself in the future.

Comment: Try debugging of a small example!

Answer (score 1):

Create a swap method to make it clearer (both for us and yourself):

```
private void swap(List<Integer> values, x, y) {
    int temp = values.get(x);
    values.set(x, values.get(y));
    values.set(y, temp);
}
```

Other suggestions:

- name your class `BubbleSort` rather than `bubbleSort`. Convention for class names is to start with uppercase.
- don't pass the length as a second argument to your sort method. It's redundant and might become incorrect if someone sneakily adds an item to the list.
- rename `randomList` to `values` or `numbers` or `randomNumbers`. No need to repeat the type in the variable name.
- replace `sorted == false` with `!sorted`. This is the common and more readable notation
- `getLength` and `createList` can be private
- Consider using the `main` method to create an instance of your sorting class, with the list as a field. In that way the methods won't have to pass the list along to each other. Your code will be more readable and more object-oriented.

EDIT: you could take the separation even further and move all the static methods into a separate class called 'Application' or 'Main'. See edited code below:

Here's roughly how the code would look following my suggestions:

```
public class BubbleSort {    

    // a field
    private List<Integer> numbers;

    public BubbleSort(List<Integer> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public static List<Integer> sort() {
        boolean sorted = false;
        while(!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            for(int x = 0; x < length - 1; x++) {
                if(numbers.get(x) > numbers.get(x + 1)) {
                    sorted = false;
                    swap(x, x + 1);
                }
            }
        }     
        return numbers;
    }       

    private void swap(x, y) {
        int temp = numbers.get(x);
        numbers.set(x, numbers.get(y));
        numbers.set(y, temp);
    }

}
```

The Application class. It's purpose is to get the length from the user, create test data and set up and call a BubbleSort instance:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = getLength();
        List<Integer> unsorted = createList(length);
        System.out.println("The list before sorting:\n" + unsorted);

        // creating an instance of the BubbleSort class
        BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort(unsorted );        
        List<Integer> sorted = bubbleSort.sort();

        System.out.println("The list after sorting:\n" + sorted);
    } 

    private static int getLength() {
        System.out.println("Please enter how long you want the array to be");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        return Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    }

    private static List<Integer> createList(int length) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int x = 0 ; x < length ; x++){
            int randomnumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            numbers.add(randomnumber);
        }
        return numbers;   
    }
```

BTW Good job splitting off those methods `getLength` and `createList`. That's the right idea.

Comment: I understand all of your suggestions other than the last one, what do you mean by creating an instance, and whats a field? Sorry if they're stupid questions

Comment: You see that in my code example at the bottom. The `private List<Integer> numbers;` is a field of any BubbleSort instance. The static main method creates such an instance by doing `new BubbleSort(unsorted)`. The advantage of creating objects (instances) is that you get more encapsulation. If all your code is static it becomes much harder to separate concerns or to create readable (and testable!) code. Static code is prone to be 'procedural' in nature and forgoes the advantages of object-oriented programming.

Answer (score -1):

you made a couple of mistakes

this:

```
randomList.set((x + 1), (x));
randomList.set((x + 1), temp);
```

should be:

```
randomList.set((x + 1), randomList.get(x));
randomList.set((x), temp);
```

full method:

```
public static List<Integer> sortList(List<Integer> randomList, int length){
    boolean sorted = false;

    while(sorted == false){
        sorted = true;

        for(int x = 0 ; x < (length - 1) ; x++) {
            if(randomList.get(x) > randomList.get(x + 1)) {
                sorted = false;
                int temp = randomList.get(x + 1);
                randomList.set((x + 1), randomList.get(x));
                randomList.set((x), temp);
            }
        }
    }

    return randomList;
}
```

Comment: what's with the downvote on a correct answer. I simply corrected his mistake... nothing fancy